# C# iterate on class own elements

Tags: c#, class, loops, self

I have created a class which inherits from List: Now I want to iterate the elements of the class in the class itself and return the object if it satisfies certain criteria (e.g. its Property name):

```
protected class myList : List<Object> 
{
    getElement(string name)
    {
        ??? LOOP AND IF CONDITION ???

         return element;
    }

}
```

Can you help? Thanks

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Comment: @Bartdude This really doesn't seem like a case where that question is relevant

Comment: @BenAaronson Why not ? I see no effort to solve the problem, only a block with question marks to be filled by us. I guess any effort from the OP to help himself would have got him really close to the solution, don't you think ? So appart from the missing block of code being very small, I don't see why this is different from a "code this for me" question ?

Comment: @Bartdude I don't think it's a good question because it's something so simple and easy to look up. But it's a thing where either you know how to do it or you don't. Either he didn't know how to use `foreach`, or he didn't make the connection that `this` is what he should be iterating over. Neither of those are things you work towards, you either know them or you don't.

Comment: @BenAaronson > Indeed I get your point. I wrongly assumed that if the OP was already at "inheritance" step, he would already be knowing thee "foreach" and "this", but apparently he's not.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for `foreach(var item in this)`.

Comment: I recommend not using `var` and being explicit with your type. In complex programs it's nice to know exactly what type a variable is going to be from the definition.

Comment: it's nothing intellisense won't tell you.  It's solely your preference and shouldn't detract from this answer

Answer (score 3):

First, I would try to avoid using `List<Object>`.The problem with `Object` is, that it needs casting. Hence it is prone to errors at runtime.

Rather create your own class.
For example, a simple item, which holds a name.

```
class Item
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can simply do:

```
class myList : List<Item> 
{
    Item getItem(string name)
    {  
         foreach(var item in this)
         {
           if(item.Name==name) { return item; }
         }

         return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: `getItem` needs a return type.

Comment: `string` is a reference type, it wouldn't be boxed/unboxed, it would be upcast/downcast.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot OK right, I call it 'casting' instead of 'boxing/unboxing' now. Since casting also applys to primitive types.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want some more code for the casting, but:

```
    public Object GetElement(string name)
    {
        Object element = null;
        foreach (var item in this)
        {
            if (item.ToString() == name)
            {
                element = item;
                break;
            }
        }
        return element;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to reinvent the wheel, just use LINQ.

```
mylist.First(element => /*criteria*/);
```